# no soundex on python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I use the sqlite3 librairy on python to interact with a .db file.
With this request:

```
SELECT * FROM LesFilms F JOIN LesRealisateurs R ON (F.film_id=R.film_id) WHERE realisateur="Tim Burtyn" or soundex("Tim Burtyn")=soundex(R.realisateur) or realisateur like"T%m Burtyn" or realisateur like"Tim B%rtyn" or realisateur like"Tim Burt%n";
```

I got this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: soundex
```

Do someone already face this problem? I share the whole request in case, I'm a total beginner.

Thank you,

Elias

Comment: As the documentation explains:  "It is only available if the SQLITE_SOUNDEX compile-time option is used when SQLite is built."

Comment: @GordonLinoff A beginner can hardly be expected to know what compile-time options were chosen by the maintainers of the standard library, let alone how to rebuild the module for themselves.

Comment: Unfortunately, many OSes distribute sqlite3 libraries that are compiled with minimal extra features enabled (And often severely outdated). With C and C++ projects, it's easy to include it directly in the program instead of relying on an external library so you can use a known version and feature set, but that's harder with python. But not impossible. Search for questions about upgrading sqlite in python for a start.

Comment: @Shawn It's not impossible for a C programmer. But it is a significant problem for a programmer who is a beginner at Python, and may not know any C at all, and is unlikely to understand how to add custom C extensions to a Python environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are out of luck, as you have probably gathered from the comments. The Python standard library module `sqlite3` generally provides an up-to-date version of sqlite.

- In Python 3.9 it is 3.32.3 from June 2020.
- In Python 3.8 it is 3.31.1 from January 2020.
- In Python 3.7 and Python 2.7.17 it is 3.28.0 from April 2019.

But the Python `sqlite3` library does *not* provide optional sqlite features that come switched off by default. This includes the `soundex` function. I can't recommend that you try building your own version of the Python standard library module with the option switched on. That sort of thing is best left to Python implementers.

As an alternative you might try the [`levenshtein`](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) module: `pip install python-Levenshtein` or the [`metaphone`](https://pypi.org/project/Metaphone/) module: `pip install Metaphone`.

To use either you would need to fetch more records from the database than you really want, for example `where realisateur like "T%"` and then discard the mismatches in Python code rather than in the `where` clause.

This is not as bad as it sounds, and may have benefits. Soundex was developed in the early 20th century and so it was intended for people to be able to compute it quickly by hand. It has significant deficiencies, as shown by the many attempts in the subsequent 100 years to improve it. The primary reason for its popularity is because it is provided by many SQL implementations, not because it is particularly good.

Answer (score 0):

load your data into a dataframe then use fuzzywuzzy to find similar string words